# How Do I Show That a Polynomial Belongs To The Set of $C^ ∞$ functions?

Tags: real-analysis

How do I show that an $n^ {th}$ degree  polynomial belongs to the set of $C^ ∞$ functions?

Answer (score 2):

Prove that the derivative of a polynomial is a polynomial, and the result immediatelly follows.

Comment: To be precise one should first prove that the derivative of a polynomial *exists everywhere*. The point is still clear from your answer though (and this minor point is arguably covered by the definition of "polynomial" anyway), so +1.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what is the definition of a $C^\infty$ function? Then, during the proof use induction on $n$.

Comment: Do I just have to use Leibniz's formula?

Comment: The derivative of a simple product should be sufficient. Do you know what $C^\infty$ means?